# Designing Image Slideshow in website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to design image slide show in my website with similar functionality like the one in http://wearehunted.com/a/#/emerging/  . However I won't have small images like the one in the reference website. Instead I will have only one complete image occupying entire screen.

Can anyone help me how can I implement this. Can this be done only with CSS + html or I need to use jquery or javascript along with html and css.

Comment: I don't have any idea about this. I tried using javascript but with that I was only able to change image after specific time.

Comment: You have to ask specific questions. Post code with specyfic problem. We cant help you otherwise.

Comment: [LetMeGoogleThatForYou](http://bit.ly/QLk5IK)

Comment: @Tony : like i mentioned, i am using to design the slideshow using timer. However I need to design one similar to the link i have mentioned..

Comment: @DarkKnight - I admit, I was being flippant with my comment. As others have commented questions on SO generally need to show _some_ research effort, otherwise you are just saying "write my code for me", which is not generally well received. It's probably why your question was down-voted.

Comment: @Tony: I am not able to figure out how to do it the way it is done on site. I don't want the one with timer.

Comment: @DarkKnight - I had a quick look at the source, they are using [backbonejs](http://backbonejs.org) for their web app, which probably provides the mouse interaction. They have written a lot of their own code by the look of all the `hunted.xxxx.js` packages. Use the developer tools of your browser to research the code, as long as you are not going to just steal it ;)

Comment: @Tony: Does jquery have any such kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

For full screen slideshows I use this: http://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

It's very simple to use with plenty of options, and also has overlays to make stretched images look pretty.

Answer (score 1):

With css and html only, you won't be able to do anything like a slide show.

If you want to keep it *very* simple and light (without libraries, etc), you could simply check with javascript whether your cursor is near the left or right border. If it is nearer than a certain value, call a function that slides the picture to the asked direction (ex change it's absolute position by increasing/decreasing the `left:variable%;`)

Here is a very coarse fiddle you could rely on http://jsfiddle.net/6VdL7/
In my example, I only check for the left side, and do not check whether the picture got to the end on the right. Furthermore, I only implemented the `mousemove`.

Hope this helps you getting where you want.